# Network Manager error

Tags: networkmanager, scientific-linux

When I run NetworkManager's applet, `nm-applet`, on my Scientific Linux 6.4, I get:

```
[root@computer]# nm-applet
```

> ** (nm-applet:4157): WARNING **:   bus_init(): Could not get the session bus.  Make sure the message bus daemon is running!  Message:
>   Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote
>   application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy
>   blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network
>   connection was broken.
>
> GConf Error: Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you
>   have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See
>   http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1:
>   Failed to get connection to session: Did not receive a reply. Possible
>   causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the
>   message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout
>   expired, or the network connection was broken.)
>
> An instance of nm-applet is already running.
>
> (nm-applet:4157): GConf-WARNING **: Directory `/system/networking/connections' was not being monitored by
>   GConfClient 0x9cac60

When I pass the command `lspci -v` I get:

```
0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
Memory at f69fc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information: Len=78 <?>
Capabilities: [e8] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [d0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [13c] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 18-6d-04-ff-ff-2c-70-1a
Capabilities: [16c] Power Budgeting <?>
Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
Kernel modules: ssb
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

#### Already running?

Do you already have NetworkManager's applet, `nm-applet` running? You can confirm with this command:

```
$ pgrep -f nm-applet
```

If it returns a number, then it's already running and this is that processes PID.

#### Example

```
$ pgrep -f nm-applet
2217
```

When I try and run it a 2nd time as user `saml` I get the following message:

```
$ nm-applet 
An instance of nm-applet is already running.

** (nm-applet:32393): WARNING **: <WARN>  constructor(): Couldn't initialize the D-Bus manager.
```

If I run it as `root`:

```
$ nm-applet 
An instance of nm-applet is already running.
```

#### Running as root?

It's probably not a good idea to try and run NetworkManager's applet as root. I'd try running it as my normal user account.

#### What should I do?

For starters I would try restarting the `NetworkManager` service.

```
$ sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

Next I would make sure that the `nm-applet` wasn't already running prior to trying to run it. Perhaps killing it with this command:

```
$ pkill nm-applet
```

Third I'd attempt to use the command line tool, `nm-tool`, just as a way to confirm that the `NetworkManager` services is functioning normally.

Example:

```
$ nm-tool |less
NetworkManager Tool

State: connected

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            e1000e
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        F1:12:12:2F:7D:4E

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

- Device: wlan0  [Auto none_of_your_business_3] --------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlagn
...
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, but I still don't get any icon in the notification and there is no second device, for example your `wlan0`. Does this mean that my wifi hardware isn't installed? I have a Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-card. I installed the three Broadcom tools `b43-fwcutter`, `b43-openfwwf` and `b43-tools` through `yum`. What else should I do?

Comment: @astroboy - yeah if you don't see any wireless devices then yes, the wireless isn't being detected/setup correctly. What does `dmesg` show for the hardware?

Comment: @astroboy - are you logged in as root? Root's not going to be able to send any GUIs to whatever account you're logged into on your laptop without some additional commands. For example if that root shell, try the command `xeyes`.

Comment: When I searched `wlan` in the `dmesg` output, I found this line: `b43-phy0: Broadcom 4312 WLAN found (core revision 15)`. It seems the device is found, but I don't understand how it isn't recognized by `nm-tool`. About being root, I have to say that after your first complete answer, I am not working as root any more.

Comment: According to here: http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README.txt , it seems that Broadcom 4312 corresponds to Dell 1395, not Dell 1397. Is their difference this significant? Do you know where I can get the 1397 driver?

Comment: @astroboy - I'd search the Dell website for it and/or the broadcom site for a specific driver. You can see what devices you're using with the command `lspci -v`. Look for the hardware device and there should be the string: "Kernel driver in use" under it if it's using a kernel module. If it doesn't have one then it's not being detected correctly.

Comment: The output of `lspci -v` showed the correct device: `0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01). Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card. Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17. Memory at f69fc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]. Capabilities: <access denied>. Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge. Kernel modules: ssb`. The only strange thing is that it says access denied! But it says the same for the wired connection that is working correctly! It seems that it does recognize the device!

Comment: @astroboy - did you run that command as root or yourself? The access denied was likely the latter. Can you run it as root just to confirm this?

Comment: You are right! I added the output to the question. Does that provide any guidance on how to fix the problem?

Comment: @astroboy - yeah the driver/hardware look fine. It's got a driver/module assigned to it. Seems to be a underlying issue with this hardware, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1461502. I'll keep looking. Can you try bringing the device `wlan0` up manually? `ifup wlan0` as root might do it. To bring it down it's `ifdown wlan0`.

Comment: The output of `ifup wlan0` is: `/sbin/ifup: configuration for wlan0 not found. Usage: ifup <device name>`!

Comment: @astroboy - you ran that as root?

Comment: yes, exactly as you advised.